# How can I deploy my C exe compiled by Visual C++ 2008 Express?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, deployment, dependencies

So I have successfully compiled and ran my application. It works perfectly on my development computer.

However when I try to run it on another computer it won't run, I get the "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002)" error.

A few questions:

1. How can I know whether the resulting exe is statically or dynamically linked?
2. I suspect it is linked dynamically. Where do I put the dependent dlls?
3. Would it be possible to get everything in one exe instead?

I know I could probably figure this out between myself and Google, but I don't really have time for such an adventure. Point me in the right direction and I will perhaps vote your answer the best one...

EDIT: It turns out one of the DLLs (which I compiled myself) was compiled as Debug so it was missing some annoying Debug DLL. I re-compiled it as Release and everything worked just fine.

Comment: -1:`I know I could probably figure this out between myself and Google, but I don't really have time for such an adventure.` Forgoing your own effort, and waiting for the answer, took longer than it took for me to search and find @Bartek Banachewicz's answer.

Comment: Well, the fact it's faster doesn't necessarily render the question useless. The other guys' answers have some viable information. I +1'd it back.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: No it doesn't. However, the obvious lack of initiative and effort, as far as I've seen, generally doesn't fly on SO. [Suggestion #1 in `asking help`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) is pretty clear on what is expected of a question -- `Do Your Homework`.

Comment: Roberto: isn't SO the exact page you go to when you haven't done your homework? Besides, I rather stand on the shoulders of giants than attempting to reinvent the wheel. Especially when it comes to compilers and their issues. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You should get and install the MSVC Redistributable Package. It contains all the DLLs that are required by the applications written and compiled by MSVS.

Comment: +1 for this. I didn't know it was wrapped up in a simple package.

Answer (score 1):

When you debug|run your application in Visual Studio - you will see the list of loaded dlls in the `Output Window`. Then you can use a tool like `Process Explorer` to see what dlls your application actually loaded on the deployment machine. Comparing the two - you will have the dll that's causing the problem.

You can either couple your application with this dll in the same directory or link to it statically by linking it against the corresponding .lib file.

Comment: To be strict, it is a license violation to distribute the DLLs that came with the compiler. So either link statically, or install  [the official release of the libs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29).

Comment: You are right @Bo Persson - should only distribute the "re-distributable" package which contains that dll.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that this has to do with missing DLLs of some sort.

You can establish which libraries the compiler is set to link with under the project options:
 C++ >> code generation >> Runtime library

This setting is typically set to multi-threaded DLL or multi-threaded static for you sort of implementation

The dependant DLLs can be in the same directory as the executable file and windows will reliably find them there although there are other options depending on the nature of the DLL (used by other applications etc).

If this is your problem it should be possible to make it run as a single exe by liking to the equivalent static libraries: If you have the source for the libraries this is easy as you can compile them with the right settings, if you are just using VC's redistributables then there should be static libaries that came with the compiler an you can link to them by changing the porject settings above. If you have other third party libraries you need to find static versions that were compiled with the same settings ON THE SAME COMPILER VERSION to make it reliable.